# How to configure a String value in Websphere 7 JNDI?

Tags: websphere, jndi, websphere-7

In fact I found such message before: 
[Configuring and looking up a simple String via JNDI in WebSphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259181/configuring-and-looking-up-a-simple-string-via-jndi-in-websphere)

I want to do the "clean" way (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0611_totapally/0611_totapally.html).  Maybe I am simply too green on WebSphere, my mind is totally messed up by the article because it is showing a more complicated example.

Can someone give me a brief steps on how to configure WebSphere so that I can bind a String value in JNDI?  Thanks so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, assuming that what you want to store is a "configuration" element, I'd actually take the time and implement it using Resource Environment Providers as it's a more flexible, and obviously more portable, approach.

In order to bind a String using JNDI, use "String Namespace Bindings": http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/unam_rstring_namespace.html

Edited (to add details about ResEnv):

The factory class is a class that you write, not IBM. Here's an example for one:

```
public class MyFactory implements javax.naming.ObjectFactory {
    @Override
    public Object getObjectInstance(Object object, Name name, Context context, Hashtable env) throws NamingException {
        MyConfig cfg = new MyConfig();

        for (Enumeration e = ((Reference) object).getAll(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
            RefAddr addr = (RefAddr) e.nextElement();
            String key = addr.getType();
            Object value = addr.getContent();
            cfg.put(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

(We're assuming that `MyConfig` is a simple class with `get(String)` and `put(String, String)` methods)

Next, create a new Resource Environment Provider in WebSphere. For a Referenceable, put the fully-qualified class name of MyFactory as the "factory class" and the fully-qualified class name of MyConfig as the "class".

Next, add a Resource Environment entry. Give it a JNDI name, say `myresources/test`. Select the Referenceable from the dropdown box.

Click "Custom Properties", and add key-value pairs there.

Save the WebSphere configuration, restart your server and try again. Issue a JNDI lookup to `myresources/test`, and you'll get a `MyConfig` instance with all the custom properties you placed there.

Let us know how it went. Good luck!

Comment: Is there any reference on implementing that using Resource Enviroment Provider? From what I read in the SO question I quoted, using String Namespace Bindings seems to be a hack.  I tried to use Resource Environment Provider cannot find information on what factory class to use in creating Referenceables (I found someone used com.ibm.rpm.factory.StringFactory but I can't get it works), and how to configure a String Resource Environment Entry using that Referenceable.  It will be great if someone can give me some hints on that. :)

Comment: In fact what I want to store is actually a String only.  If it is the case, is there any factory provided by Websphere that I can directly make use of?

Comment: Though I am expecting a "cleaner" way of binding String to JNDI to avoid using the trick of "namespace binding", as no one is giving that answer, I am accepting the closest answer which is this one

Comment: the IBM link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

I posted some [JNDI configuration tips](http://www.glezen.org/howto/AppConfig/index.html#snsb) along with their pros and cons.  It's a bit dated but should still apply.