# Correct location to place the properties file for a struts web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, struts2, war

I am developing a Struts 2 web application, all the constant values and hardcoded values are moved to a properties file along with those, the constants which are specific to environment like Data source name, some of the server connection urls and few user ids are also placed in the properties file.

Initially I placed the properties file in the class path and accessed using resource bundle as below

```
 ResourceBundle RESOURCE_BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle("config\appProps");
```

Problem with that is Because of those environment specific constants for ever environment(DEV / UAT / PROD) a separate war needs to be generated by changing the properties file environment specific constants value, to avoid that I am using below process

I kept the properties file absolute path in the context parameter of the web.xml and get the path from the context and reading the properties file as below

```
   Properties prop = new Properties();
   prop.load(new FileInputStream("<<file system absolute path from context param>>"));
```

This eliminated the process of generating different war for each environment as path on the server can be maintained same, but I came to know that security wise we should not use absolute paths like that which might expose the server file system details

Please let me know What is the correct way of loading the properties file in a web application by considering security as well as eliminating generation of different war files for each environment.

Thanks.

Comment: Expose server file system details to *who*?

Comment: Hi Dave Newton when we made our code to scan through some app security tool it gave that as a high risk saying that, there are chances that hackers can exploit the file system so we should not use absolute paths in the application. Not exactly sure what ever that security tool told is valid or not as we are having the path in web.xml not in any JSP file.

Comment: If they're already exploiting the file system it's too late to do anything of value. If it doesn't complain about web.xml paths you can use init-params, you can use JNDI on the app server, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe hoist the whole properties object into JNDI, that would fix it, but implementations may be server specific. And now you've got a new problem; make sure that the properties are loaded before you read them.

Comment: Thanks Friso & Dave Newton for showing a new direction but I am not able to get much information regarding using JNDI for properties, all the information about JNDI I am able to get is regarding how to configure JNDI data source for db connection. Only place I could able to find info is http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html under Generic Java Bean resources section but that is also not complete keeping all properties as attributes doesnt feel correct. My application is in IBM WAS can you please point me to any specific examples which show how to do this.

Comment: Also please let me know using JNDI for this purpose will cause any other impacts or its fine

Comment: I'm a little rusty on WAS, but if memory serves, it was easier than Tomcat. As JNDI is a tree you could use String properties and have one key/value pair per JDNI entry. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312699/how-to-configure-a-string-value-in-websphere-7-jndi otherwise http://www.glezen.org/howto/AppConfig/index.html#extprops might fit your needs